# python opening multiple files and using multiple directories at once

Tags: python, loops, directory

I can open two files at once using with open, now if i am going through two directories using this same method,

```
f = open(os.path.join('./directory/', filename1), "r") 
f2 = open(os.path.join('./directory2/', filename1) "r")

with open(file1, 'a') as x: 
   for line in f:
     if "strin" in line:
          x.write(line) 
with open(file2, 'a') as y:
   for line in f1:
      if "string" in line:
          y.write(line)
```

merge these into one method

Comment: what do you want to merge, the two files into one?

Comment: no, what I am doing is opening two different files in two different directories, looking for the same strings though and editing them, the only difference is that they are in different directories @smushi

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: so your saying that the two files do no open?

Comment: i want to make it with `open(filename, 'a') as x, open(filename, 'a') as y`, then  go through the lines for f and f1 (different directories) and edit the two separate files using the two different directories, I am looking for the same strings, something like this `for line in f and f1, x.write(line in f) y.write(line in f1)`, I have them into different loops and method

Comment: why do you want to try and do this?

Comment: If you're just trying to be less redundant, you could just wrap it around a function that takes a directory that you want to work with as a parameter. That would reduce repeated uses of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudocode (`for line in f and f1, x.write(line in f) y.write(line in f1)`) has the same effect as the original code you posted, and isn't useful unless there is something about the corresponding lines in the two files that you want to process.

But you can use `zip` to combine iterables to get what you want

```
import itertools

with open(os.path.join('./directory', filename1)) as r1, \
     open(os.path.join('./directory2', filename1)) as r2, \
     open(file1, 'a') as x, \
     open(file2, 'a') as y:
     for r1_line, r2_line in itertools.izip_longest(r1, r2):
         if r1_line and "string" in line:
             x.write(r1_line) 
         if r2_line and "string" in line:
             y.write(r1_line)
```

- I put all of the file objects in a single `with` clause using `\` to escape the new line so that python sees it as a single line
- The various permutations of `zip` combine iterables into a sequence of tuples.
- I chose izip_longest because it will continue to emit lines from both files, using None for the files that empty first, until all lines are consumed. `if r1_line ...` just makes sure we aren't at the Nones for file that has been fully consumed.
- This is a strange way to do things - for the example you've given, it's not the better choice.